# Digit Extractor

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Problem: The method has one parameters an integer. Break the integer into a sequence of individual digits in reverse order. The result will be an array containing the individual numbers in reverse order.

Tester:
digitExtractor(16384) → {4, 8, 3, 6, 1}

digitExtractor(123) → {3, 2, 1}

digitExtractor(23) → {3, 2}

digitExtractor(-123) → {-1, 2, 3} (I have a problem with this one)

```
public int[] digitExtractor(int number)
{
   int[] arr;
   ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   if(number == 0)
   {
      digits.add(number);
   }
   if(number < 0)
   {
      number *= -1;
   }
   while (number != 0)
   {
      digits.add(number % 10);
      number /= 10;
   }
   arr = new int[digits.size()];
   for(int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
   {
      arr[i] = digits.get(i);
   }
   return arr;
}
```

My code works, except for the negative number. I don't know how to fix it. Any tips?

Comment: You have multipled negative numbers with -1 and this os rightly done. But you have to multiply with -1 again to retain your negative sign.

Comment: is it on purpose that the negative one is not reversed in order?

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment and try this:

```
public int[] digitExtractor(int number)
{
   int[] arr;
   boolean flag=false;
   ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   if(number == 0)
   {
      digits.add(number);
   }
   if(number < 0)
   {
      number *= -1;
      flag=true;
   }
   while (number != 0)
   {
      digits.add(number % 10);
      number /= 10;
   }
   arr = new int[digits.size()];
   for(int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
   {
      arr[i] = digits.get(i);
   }
   if(flag){
       arr[digits.size()-1]*=-1;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand it perfectly now, thanks so much!

Comment: @byerlyfactor If this answer has helped you then mark it as accepted. If you need some explaination, then comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this :

```
public static int[] digitExtractor(int number) {
    boolean negative = number < 0;
    String myNumber = String.valueOf(number);
    myNumber = new StringBuilder(myNumber).reverse().toString();
    int size = negative ? myNumber.length() - 1 : myNumber.length();
    int[] arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(myNumber.charAt(i));
    }

    if (negative) {
        arr[size - 1] = 0 - arr[size - 1];
    }
    return arr;
}
```